# Compiling and running a java program in command prompt

Tags: java, path, compilation, classpath, command-prompt

I have written a simple hello world program given below

```
package helloworld;

public class helloWorld 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I'm using Windows 7 and have set my CLASSPATH and PATH variables in the environment variables window as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;
```

The program is located at

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\javaAssignment\src\helloWorld
```

So, basically when i try to run it in my command prompt, the following happens

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\javaAssignment\src\helloWorld>javachelloWorld.java

C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\javaAssignment\src\helloWorld>java helloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: helloWorld (wrong name: helloworld/helloWorld)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: helloWorld.  Program will exit.
```

The program seems to be compiling fine and does not throw any errors. But when i try to run it, it says than exceptions have occurred.
I tried looking up on Google thinking that setting my PATH and CLASSPATH was wrong, but I don't seem to find any issues with that.

Comment: have you defined any package ?

Comment: @Kakarot Yes I have. Sorry, Edited the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your helloWorld.java file is in a package, you can run as follows :

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\javaAssignment\src\
java packageName.helloWorld
```

Run the code from outside the helloworld package directory i.e from src directory (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\javaAssignment\src)

Also check if the name of your java file is the same as your class name (helloWorld.java)

Also it seems that the name of your package is helloworld (all in small letters) however the folder name is helloWorld (note that W is capital) both the names need to match.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it out. But the same exceptions are being thrown by it

Comment: try running the code from inside helloworld package directory

Comment: Check the name of the java file is it same as class file ?

Comment: Yes, both are named helloWorld. Both helloWorld.java and helloWorld.class exist in 
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\javaAssignment\src\helloWorld

Comment: i found the culprit the name of your package is helloworld (all in small letters) whereas the folder is named helloWorld (note that W is capital) make it small alphabets

Comment: I just checked. The folder, javafile and the classfile are all named as helloWorld. There seems to be no discrepancies in that.

Comment: change that to : package helloWorld;

Comment: package name is not case sensitive I think. The package is named as helloWorld only. With the caps. But in the code it is getting printed as helloworld.

Comment: did you try running the code from helloWorld folder or src folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are in the directory containing your helloWorld.class file when you issue the command

```
java helloWorld
```

Comment: Yeah, I reset my CLASSPATH to the director where my helloWorld.class exists. Tried running it again. Still throwing the same exceptions.

Comment: I mean using cd and cd.. in the command prompt. Navigate to the directory that is holding your helloWorld.class file before issuing the java command

Comment: The helloWorld.class file has been created in the same folder on compilation
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\javaAssignment\src\helloWorld
So, I dont need to change the directory, right?